# How to get a button in my custom adapter for my listview to call a phone number

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, android-listview, custom-adapter

I take in the addresses and information of stores and list then in a listview, by name, address, city/state and phn number. I am trying so that the system will use the phone to call a number. But, i get an activity not found exception.

```
            public static class MyRow
        {
            String storeName;
            String streetAdress;
            String location;
            String phn;

            MyRow(String str1, String str2, String str3, String str4)
            {
                storeName = str1;
                streetAdress = str2;
                location = str3;
                phn= str4;
            }
        }

        public static class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
        {
            ArrayList<MyRow> specList;
            Context conty;

            CustomAdapter(Context c)
            {
                conty = c;
                specList = new ArrayList<Row>();
                ArrayList<String> storeName = new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayList<String> streetAdress = new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayList<String> location = new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayList<String> phn= new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < ar.size(); i++)
                {
                    storeName.add(ar.get(i).get(0).toString());
                    streetAdress.add(ar.get(i).get(2).toString());
                    location.add(ar.get(i).get(3).toString() + ", " 
                    + ar.get(i).get(4).toString() + " " + ar.get(i).get(5).toString());
                    phn.add(ar.get(i).get(7).toString());
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < ar.size(); i++)
                {
                    specList.add(new MyRow(storeName.get(i), streetAdress.get(i), 
                            location.get(i), phn.get(i)));
                }
            }       

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return specList.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return specList.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) conty.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                final View rw = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
                TextView name = (TextView) rw.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                TextView adress = (TextView) rw.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                TextView location = (TextView) rw.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                TextView phn = (TextView) rw.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                final Row temp = specList.get(position);
                name.setText(temp.storeName);
                adress.setText(temp.streetAdress);
                location.setText(temp.location);
                phn.setText("  Phone:" + temp.phn);
                Button call = (Button) rw.findViewById(R.id.button1);
                call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                        i.setData(Uri.parse(temp.country));
                        rw.getContext().startActivity(i);//I get an error here stating: Activity not found exception.
                    }

                });

                return rw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you added permission in manifest file?

Comment: for the dailer yea: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ACTION_DIAL :

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("tel:" + number);
Intent i= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, uri);
```

For use ACTION_CALL anyway, you need special permission (android.permission.CALL_PHONE) :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL

Note: there will be restrictions on which applications can initiate a call; most applications should use the ACTION_DIAL.

Comment: I did it's still the same problem

Comment: your device support phone call? you can get this in an emulator/tablet/etc ?